# GPU Computing - # of GPUs supported

Tags: windows, linux, windows-7, gpu, opencl

I currently have a desktop with 6 GPUs ( 3x HD 5970s ) in non-crossfire mode. Unfortunately, it seems that Windows 7 64bit only supports up to 4 GPUs. I have not been able to find a reliable source to deny or confirm this.

If windows 7 has this limitation, is there a Linux flavor that supports more than 4 GPUs?

In-case you are wondering, this is not for gaming but high-speed single precision computing. With this current setup ( if I can find 6gpu support ) I am looking to reach 13.8 Teraflops.

Also, my motherboard does support 3 16x pci-xpress gen2 slots... and I have a 1500w powersupply plugged into a 20amp outlet. Windows is able to detect all 6 cores.. although, 2 of which displays the warning "Drivers failed to load".

To recap:

**- Can windows support 6 GPUs?**

**- If not, does Linux?**

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow TTK. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not the place for hardware related questions. This is better asked at the sister (or is it brother) site, superuser.com. In a few minutes, your question will be closed and migrated over. Good luck with the solution to your issue.

Comment: Are you using the latest drivers? Seems like this might be a driver issue. I feel like linux will also depend on drivers

Comment: Have you asked over here?
http://forums.amd.com/devforum/categories.cfm?catid=390
They tackle hardware as well as OpenCL programming issues over there.

Comment: I am using the lastest drivers downloaded from the ati.amd.com website. I have not asked on those forums yet... but I will be sure to do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Up to this point, I was not able to confirm or deny the support for more than 4 GPUs on Windows 7 64bit. However, I was able to find various users that have been able to run 5 and 6 gpus on Ubuntu 8.04 64bit.

http://forums.amd.com/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=328&threadid=122135

**So, to answer my own question: If you are going to build a GPU Powerhouse utilizing >4 GPUs, currently the only documented solution involves 64bit Ubuntu.**

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

To get Windows to support 5 GPUs I had to go to Windows 8.1 from 7.  I am unsure what the actual limit for 8.1 is, though.